# set Bounds on Leaflet map according to map zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I am working on a forked OSM/leaflet/overpass API application which has its own max bounds declared.
That way, any request to Overpass API is restricted to bounds declared

```
var mapBounds = { south: 50.8025, west: 0.3724, north: 50.8785, east: 0.5290 };
var LBounds = L.latLngBounds([mapBounds.south, mapBounds.west], [mapBounds.north, mapBounds.east]);
```

The query to Overpass API is done

```
...
    else queryBbox += '[bbox:' + [mapBounds.south, mapBounds.west, mapBounds.north, mapBounds.east].join(',') + ']';
...
```

Need to change the bounding box (mapBounds) to allow to navigate worldwide, and set them as bbox, so requests to Overpass API are for that map area only.

so i've done

```
else queryBbox += '[bbox:' + map.getBounds().toBBoxString() + ']';
```

But I can't make it work .. Overpass returns no results

> addition:

meanwhile i got closer, i tried to see what happens onMoveEnd

```
onMoveEnd: function () {
    console.log(queryBbox);
```

console record seems to return coordinates:

```
[out:json][bbox:0.38512229919433594,50.82990293001779,0.549917221069336,50.86404449323755];(nwr[tourism=museum];);out tags center qt 250;
```

But they are reversed

for comparison: this is how the original query looks like

```
[out:json][bbox:50.8025,0.3724,50.8785,0.529];(nwr[tourism=museum];);out tags center qt 250;
```

Comment: It is really hard for me to understand what you want. Do you want to search only in the visible bounds? or in the mapBounds? Or do you want to search in the bounds until zoom 10 (or the bounds if zoom higher than 10) but the map minZoom should be 0?

Comment: Hi Falke, i slightly changed my text. Need to search visible bounds only. There is already a minZoom for search existing in a function (something around 14)

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong, it should look like that: https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];out%20skel%20qt;node[tourism=attraction];&bbox=0.427393913269043,50.84410451978967,0.5097913742065431,50.85710981721644;

Do you build the url by your self or over a library? If you use a library, look into if you have defined some wrong.

To create a own request create the url and then make a http request:

```
function getOverpassData(){
    var bbox = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
    var _url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];out%20skel%20qt;node[tourism=attraction];";

    var bboxurl = _url+"&bbox="+bbox;
    console.log(bboxurl);
    // And then use $.ajax(bboxurl) or the normal js http request to get data.
}
```

Comment: I had a typo in my call, so i fixed it... seems that the issue is, that populated coordinates for bbox are reversed. I have updated my text above

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix my issue while reading (closer) to Leaflet's documentation.

> toBBoxString()  Returns a string with bounding box coordinates in a
>   'southwest_lng,southwest_lat,northeast_lng,northeast_lat' format.
>   Useful for sending requests to web services that return geo data.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlngbounds-tobboxstring

But the fact is, that Overpass API does not return responses in GeoJSON format ... so my hack with toBBoxString() was not suitable , aka that's why i got false responses.
Instead, this one worked fine, all requests are now successful

```
else queryBbox += '[bbox:' + map.getBounds().getSouth() +',' + map.getBounds().getWest() +',' + map.getBounds().getNorth() +',' + map.getBounds().getEast() + ']';
```

I hope that someone might have a more elegant solution before i vote for mine